# How do I remove the space above my name and position my email and Linkedin links well?

Tags: cv

```
\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
 \hfill\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=2.5cm]{CPREWRITTEN.png}
  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{{\LARGE Ankit Gupta}} & Email: %\href{mailto:gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}{gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}\\
  \href{mailto:gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}{\textcolor{LightRubineRed}{gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}} & Mobile:~~~+91-861-889-1003 \\
  Linkedin: \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankitg0812/}{\textcolor{blue!90!}{ https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankitg0812/}}

\end{tabular*}
```

[image]

[image: This is how I want it to look]

Comment: what should the finished image look like -- a hands sketch perhaps?

Comment: I added. I'm sorry I'm new to Stack Exchange and can't figure a way to properly add edits.
I'm low on time so I'll be happy for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate, hyperref, multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    %----------HEADING-----------------
%   \hfill\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=2.5cm]{CPREWRITTEN.png}
    
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{{\LARGE Ankit Gupta}} 
            &\multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=2.5cm]{CPREWRITTEN.png}} \\
        Email:   \href{mailto:gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}{\textcolor{RubineRed}{gupta.ankit0812@gmail.com}}  
            &  \\
        Mobile:~~~+91-861-889-1003
            &   \\
        Linkedin: \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankitg0812/}{\textcolor{blue!90!}{ https://www.linkedin.com/in/ankitg0812/}}
        
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes this works!
Thanks!